# bash script: gnome-terminal does not parse arguments

Tags: bash, scripts, gnome-terminal

Using 14.04. I read several posts here and changed the command; however `gnome-terminal` comes with an error:

```
Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

I have a bash script in which several functions are declared and some of them I want to use in an other terminal session. Instead of `export` I used `declare` (to be able to use it in multiple sessions later).

This is the command in the bash script, which gives me the error:

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"$(declare -f compile_init); do compile_init; $(declare -f choose_url); do choose_url; bash\""
```

BTW I also tried it with: export DISPLAY=:0.0 first